# usages of out parameter in conditional flow and CA1002 fxcop error

Tags: c#, fxcop, out-parameters

I have a xml parsing code where I am parsing multiple nodes and attributes from xml. Using short circuit, I am able to avoid if in my code because I want to continue processing only in positive case. But I am getting fxcop error `CA1002` for parameter as out usages.

How can I remove the fxcorp error?

```
public bool parseNode()
{
    bool success = false;
    string val1;
    string val2;
    string val3

    success = TryGetAttributeValue(attribName1, out val1) &&
              TryGetAttributeValue(attribName2, out val2) &&
              TryGetAttributeValyue(attribName3, out val3);

    if(success)
    {
        // do work
    }
}

public bool TryGetAttributeValue(string attribName, out string value)
{
}
```

Comment: CA1002 appears to be "Do not expose generic lists".  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182142.aspx  Are you sure that's the right error code?  How about CA1021, "Avoid out parameters"?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182131.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're talking about [CA1021](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182131.aspx) (*Avoid out parameters*) and not [CA1002](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182142.aspx) (*Do not expose generic lists*), FxCop is complaining about the `out` parameter of your `TryGetAttributeValue()` method.

You can refactor that method so it returns the attribute value instead of storing it in an `out` parameter, and have it return `null`if the attribute does not exist. From there, you can use the [null-coalescing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator `??` to keep the same control flow:

```
public string TryGetAttributeValue(string attribName)
{
    // Return attribute value, or null.
}

public bool ParseNode()
{
    if ((TryGetAttributeValue(attribName1)
        ?? TryGetAttributeValue(attribName2)
        ?? TryGetAttributeValue(attribName3)) != null) {
        // Do work.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are actually talking about CA1021, which fits your description better: [This is the MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182131%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) about this violation. You can change the method type to something other than `public` or `protected` (`internal` ?)

Otherwise:

> To fix a violation of this rule that is caused by a value type, have
>   the method return the object as its return value. If the method must
>   return multiple values, redesign it to return a single instance of an
>   object that holds the values.

If you are not able/willing to change the protection type or change the code to simply return the string, then you will have to [ignore this fxcop rule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429303%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#IgnoringRulesDuringAnalysis) .  Which, is not a horrible thing. You have to decide which rules seem pertinent and which do not.

Your code would have to be something like `GetAttributeValue`, and use a check for null if you want to avoid this fxcop rule. Or, you could create a special class and use a [Null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern), but that seems to be way too much overkill.

In the end, you are in control of your code, and not all rules are meant for everybody.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's CA1002? Because that one is the `Do not expose generic lists` rule according to google. Anyway, I know that FxCop has rule which warns about using `out` (and also `ref`) parameters as they are not considered best practice for OO (your are supposed to return a object which represents the result).

In order to get rid of the warning you would need to change your method `TryGetAttributeValue` to not use `out` parameters.

As a side note: Microsoft apparently violated this rule in the various `TryGet` and `TryParse` methods. So just because FxCop says so, it does not make it necessarily a bad choice.

Answer (score 0):

[If you read the whole article, you can see at the end the following:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms182131.aspx)

> Methods that implement the Try pattern, such as
>   Int32.TryParse, do not raise this violation.

So as long as your methode return a `bool` and has a name like `TryGetSomething`, you are not violating the rule if you use the `out` parameter.